# Duplicating a contact in the Samsung contacts app

Tags: samsung, contacts

How can I duplicate a contact in the phone memory of a Samsung Android 11 smartphone without entering the same information again ? This is helpful for example when adding a person in the same organization as an already existing person in this organization.

ChatGPT told me to use the duplicate option in the options menu when editing the contact but there is no options menu in edit mode and the options menu outside edit mode does not contain a duplicate option.

Samsung Contacts app is version 12.7.05.5.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know is to email it yourself -

- Open Contacts
- Find Contact
- Open the desired Contact
- Select Share
- Select VCF
- Select Email
- Email it to yourself
- Open Email
- Click on attachment
- Agree to View the .vcf file
- Select Contacts to view it
- Select Import
- Select the Account to import it into (Use google account/phone/sim)depending on where you have your contacts assigned to.
- Press Import

Comment: At least in my Samsung Contacts app version, one needs to edit and save the existing contact before importing it again in order to prevent from importing into the already existing contact which would prevent from duplicating it.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @RohitGupta's answer, I've found an easier solution without involving eMail:

- Open the desired contact
- Select Share
- Select VCF
- Select any text editor to share with (I've used "Simple generic text editor" from F-Droid)
- Save as `*.vcf` in a shareable phone memory location (maybe Downloads folder)
- Edit and save the existing contact in the Contacts app (needed to prevent from importing into the already existing contact which would prevent from duplicating it)
- Select the just saved `*.vcf` file using any file manager
- Select Contacts to view it
- Select Import
- Select Phone Memory, press OK.

Comment: Note, you are allowed to tick your own answer after 24hrs. plus oned it.

Comment: @RohitGupta, yes, but this isn't really a good solution, so I decided to leave it unticked in the hope for a better solution in the future.